# How to re-scale camera footage using pygame.camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, camera

Hey does anyone know how to re-scale pygame camera footage I have looked everywhere but there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this. I have tried using `pygame.transform.scale` but the pygame screen doesn't even pop up
Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print("Using camera %s ..." % cameras[0])

cam1 = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])
cam1.start()

img1 = cam1.get_image()

flags = DOUBLEBUF
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100), flags, 4)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.set_allowed(KEYDOWN)
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.camera.quit()

    img1 = cam1.get_image().convert()


    scaled_img1 = pygame.transform.scale(img1, (500, 500))
    screen.blit(scaled_img1, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You didnt update this code, can you do that please?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had updated it, its fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.scale`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) does not scale the *Surface* itself, but returns a new scaled *Surface*:

```py
scaled_img1 = pygame.transform.scale(img1, (100, 100))
```

See also  [How to change an image size in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046376/how-to-change-an-image-size-in-pygame/66611330#66611330) and [Pygame cannot make image bigger over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395844/pygame-cannot-make-image-bigger-over-time/68395966#68395966).

Additionally you have to `blit` the image after scaling the image:

```py
while 1:
    # [...]

    scaled_img1 = pygame.transform.scale(img1, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(scaled_img1 , (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```